# Unable to use stty in Mac's Zsh

Tags: mac

Unix Power Tools -book recommends to use the following command if you do not want to get any notification of running process

```
stty -topstop
```

or

```
stty -topstop
```

Both commands give me

```
stty: illegal option -- topstop
usage: stty [-a|-e|-g] [-f file] [options]
```

**How can you use the command in OS/X's Zsh?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not seem to be a zsh issue. This is an issue with the specific implementation of the command **stty** on your system.

To investigate a new command, remember:

```
 $ man [command]
```

There are also manual pages online, so if your particular system does not have the man pages installed, you can still get the needed info.

Many modern utilities have built-in help info. Try

```
$ [command] -h
```

or

```
$ [command] --help
```

to figure out what options the [command] you're interested in has on your system.

I am also suspecting that you have a typo. Do you really mean "topstop"? This does not seem to be a valid option.

Answer (score 1):

Before running the command, you must tell zsh to unlock your terminal:

```
ttyctl -u
stty -tostop
```

Comment: I get the same error message. -- I need to try your code in Ubuntu. It will likely work.

Answer (score 0):

stty doesn't seem to have a -topstop option; is it supposed to be -tostop?  Use

```
man stty
```

for details on the stty command and its options.